# Como criar um teste para uma função com um service dentro?

Tags: node.js, mocha, chai, testes

Eu tenho o código abaixo e consegui criar um teste para ele, quando ele entra no erro 400 e no 200. Porém, não consigo fazer com que o teste entre no `catch`.

Estou usando o Mocha e Chai.

```
myController.approve = (request, response) => {
    let { id, text } = request.body;

    if (!myController.idValidId(id)) {
        response.status(400).send();
        return;
    }

    myService.approve(id, text)
    .then(() => {
        response.send(200);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        response.status(error.response.status).json({
            approved: false,
            error: "Erro ao aprovar documento",
        });
    });
};
```

Meu teste:

```
describe('POST document', function () {
    it('should return OK for the document', function (done) {
        request(server)
        .post('/my-url')
        .send({
            id: 1,
            text: 'Teste de Observação',
        })
        .then(function(res){
            expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
            done();
        })
    });

    it('should return ERROR for document ID invalid', function (done) {
        config.mockDocumentApproval();

        request(server)
        .post('/my-url')
        .send({
            id: 'not-a-number-valid',
            text: 'Teste de Observação',
        })
        .then(function(res){
            expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(400);
            done();
        })
    });

    it('should return error for document', function (done) {
        // Erro ao entrar no tach
    });
});
```

Como eu faço para meu teste entrar no erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não conheço os detalhes de implementação mas seria uma forma de forcar o erro. Para os exemplos de minhas tentativas eu vou destacar apenas o trecho que eu modifiquei em relação ao seu código:

Uma maneira para tentar forçar o 500 seria enviar o id um número negativo.

```
.send({
   id: -1,
   text: 'Teste de Observação',
})
```

Uma segunda maneira é mandar o número 0.

```
.send({
   id: 0,
   text: 'Teste de Observação',
})
```

Outra tentativa é mandar um caractere especial

```
.send({
       id: '#@',
       text: 'Teste de Observação',
})
```

Outra possibilidade é enviar nulo ou vazio.

```
.send({
       id: null,
       text: 'Teste de Observação',
})
//----------------
.send({
       id: '',
       text: 'Teste de Observação',
})
```

Outra possibilidade é não enviar.

```
.send({
       text: 'Teste de Observação',
})
```

Uma coisa que poderia tentar era enviar um número gigante (que force o overflow para os tipos `long` e `int`

```
.send({
       id: 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999,
       text: 'Teste de Observação',
})
```

Caso mesmo assim não consiga, uma possibilidade para o 500 é fazer 2 cadastros consecutivos com o mesmo `id`, isso vai forçar o banco de dados o erro 500 caso esteja validando id único. Validação de chave primária (constraint `UNIQUE`).

Espero que de alguma forma ocorra um erro 500.

Comment: Então, até dá o erro, mas o Coverage aponta que a linha do response.status() falta testar. Estranho.

Comment: mas a cobertura aumentou? pois as vezes bug a exibição porque o comando está sendo feito em mais de uma linha.

Comment: Não aumentou. Continua dizendo que não entrou no catch

Comment: Esse teu erro.response.status está estranho, tenta retornar só um número 500 lá onde vc seta o status, estou desconfiado que esta variável não possui este aninhamento. Tipo o `error.response` ser undefined ou null sabe? Ai isso está causando um erro dentro do catch. Uma maneira de debuggar é colocando um console.log(error), verifica se estão definidos todos os valores utilizados. tipo `error.response`, se o `error.response.status` existe. Caso sim, verifica o tipo, pois pode ser que ele esteja retornando uma string, porém vc está utilizando a sintaxe de objeto. Aí é só fazer um parse.